# How to add a union all result in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-workbench

I want to do a query where I have a total of each equipment: quantity * costs.

Now I want to do an MySQL query where I create a temp column which does the following:

```
Total - Total of Totals
80    -  80
90    -  170
100   -  270
```

Now I have a code like this:

```
Select total
from equipment
UNION ALL
select sum(total) from equipment;
```

Which gives a total of totals underneath the totals.
I would like to separate that and do it sequentially beside it.

Comment: Please add some info about your meaning  of the word `sequential `. (Sample input, and sample output. You can use [edit] to add this info to your question)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql 8 you can use window functions for that

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
   quantity * costs as total as total
FROM 
equipment)
    select
      total,
      sum(total) over (order by total) as cumulative_sum
    from CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(quantity * costs) AS total
FROM equipment
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
```

At the bottom of the result set there will appear a record with `NULL` as the `id`, whose total will be over all groups.

Comment: Thank you but the quantity * costs is not summing up with each row as it is :/ but the last value is a total of totals.

I would like it to be sequential like

id - total
1  - 100
2  -  2000
3  -  2100
Total - 123454566

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a window function, something like this:

```
select (quantity * costs) as total,
       sum(quantity * costs) over (order by quantity * costs) as running_total
from equipment;
```

I would actually expect that your existing total is the result of an aggregation.  Your question is unclear on what, but you can use window functions with aggregation functions:

```
select sum(quantity * costs) as total,
       sum(quantity * costs) over (order by sum(quantity * costs)) as running_total
from equipment
group by <something>
```